# mysql query filter LIKE not working properly

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a column `campaign_name` and user might type and look for increase sensitive string keyword. For example they entered `"adopt a patient"`. But inside my table the `campaign_name`: I have `"adopt-a-patient"`

```
+----------------
|campaign_name  |
+----------------
|adopt-a-patient|
-----------------
select * from campaign where campaign_name LIKE '%adopt a patient%';
return ZERO result
```

My `campaign_name` collation is already set to `utf8_general_ci`. But if users entered exactly the word `"adopt-a-patient"` the result returned as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated. Anyway I'm implementing it on `django` app. I'm just debugging it inside `HeidiSQL`.

Comment: Well it will not convert the spaces in `'ADOPT A PATIENT'` to hyphens `adopt-a-patient`.

Comment: Full Text Searching can provide much more flexibility to handle with variable user input for a same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps replacing the spaces with `'%'` would do what you want:

```
where campaign_name like concat('%', replace('ADOPT A PATIENT', ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Note:  This allows any length strings.  If you want to allow only one character, then use `'_'` instead:

```
where campaign_name like concat('%', replace('ADOPT A PATIENT', ' ', '_'), '%')
```

Comment: do you know how can i integrate it with my django app?

Answer (score 0):

Use `%` between to get perfect result

```
select * from campaign where campaign_name LIKE '%adopt%a%patient%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three words in search filter: "ADOPT", "A", "CAMPAIGN".
You may want to do one of these two things:

1) search all rows matching at least one word

```
SELECT * FROM campaign 
WHERE (campaign_name LIKE '%adopt%') OR (campaign_name LIKE '%a%')
OR (campaign_name LIKE '%patient%);
```

(it should be better consider only words longer than 2 chars)

2) search all rows matching all three words:

```
SELECT * FROM campaign 
WHERE (campaign_name LIKE '%adopt%') AND (campaign_name LIKE '%a%')
AND (campaign_name LIKE '%patient%);
```

if you want that the searched words are in any order
or

```
SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE (campaign_name LIKE '%adopt%a%campaigne%');
```

if you want that the searched words are in the order they have been written.